# A complex version of the Cahiers topos

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, topos-theory, synthetic-differential

Has anyone tried defining a complex version of the Cahiers topos?

If we take the definition of $C^\infty$-rings, replace "smooth" with "holomorphic" (of course, one has to take care to replace the domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ - or perhaps a Stein manifold?), replace a real Weil algebra with its complex counterpart, take the full subcategory of "holomorphic rings" analogous to the one used to define the Cahiers topos, then define a Grothendieck topology on it and take the sheaves on it, all analogous to the real case, I assume we'd get a topos, analogous to the Cahiers topos, in which Kock-Lawvere should be validated.

However, I cannot find any material on this, so I was suspecting if this approach is in fact unproductive (e.g. the resulting topos is too small or even trivial, or perhaps too large). Do we know anything about this "complex Cahiers topos"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been done, see the article [EFC-algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/EFC-algebra) and references therein.

In particular, the paper of Pridham constructs the topos of ∞-sheaves on the site of (derived) Stein spaces and explores its properties.  The resulting ∞-topos is a model for synthetic complex geometry and is a holomorphic analogue of the (derived) Dubuc topos, which is bigger than the Cahiers topos.